# only javascript sanitization using google caja

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to sanitize the inputs given to a nodejs server using [google-caja sanitizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-caja-sanitizer).

However, it santizes `>` and `<` symbols too.

My application needs to store html characters as they are, except for `<script>`, `<style>` and `javascript` functions.

Is there anyway I can only sanitize `javascript` functions using 
`google-caja-sanitizer` or perhaps using another plugin for node/express?

Comment: @RobC that helped a little. this i am going to use in backend to store the inputs into database. i have a scenario my users will give me input like **xyz>asdfasd<adfasdf**. this has to be stored as it is. but google-caja-sanitizer gives output like **xyz&gt;asdfasd** . any suggestions how to use for my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bleach](https://github.com/ecto/bleach) provides me what i want. it has whitelisting options also.

```
var bleach = require('bleach');

var whitelist = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'i',
    'em',
    'strong',
    'div'
];
var options = {
    mode: 'white',
    list: whitelist
}

bleach.sanitize('xyz>asdfasd<adfasdf'); //outputs xyz>asdfasd<adfasdf
bleach.sanitize("test<div data-fruit='Apple'>Apple</div>"); //outputs testApple
bleach.sanitize("test<div data-fruit='Apple'>Apple</div>",options); //outputs test<div data-fruit='Apple'>Apple</div>
```